# Django Form Checkbox Automatically Update Database via Ajax

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can find lots of information on how to make a checkbox that automatically updates the database `onclick` using php/ajax rather than having a user click the checkbox then press another button to submit the form, but I can't find anything on doing this in Django.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: not much of a difference you use ajax and point it to view

Comment: Thanks again @iklinac . I thought that would be the case but was taken back when I could find nothing on it with a Google search. Ive never used ajax but I guess its time i take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using JQuery Ajax in the template and by creating an "API view" in your views.py that is basically just a regular view that returns a `JSONResponse` after checking to verify the request is Ajax. As an example of the "API" option, using JQuery:

In your urls.py:

```
...
path('/api/post_form/', post_form_api, name="post_form_api"),
...
```

In your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button_or_object_id").click(function(){
            var csrfToken = $( "input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
            var form_field1 = $("#myTextArea").val();
                $.ajax({ url: '{% url 'post_form_api' %}',
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {'form_field1':form_field1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken.val()},
                                    cache: false
                           }).done(function(data) {
                                if (data.result === true){
                                    alert(data.message);
                               }
                           });
                      });
                  });
            </script>
```

Alternatively, you can get all the form fields at once:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button_or_object_id").click(function(){
            var form_data = $("#my_form_id").serialize();
                $.ajax({ url: '{% url 'post_form_api' %}',
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: form_data,
                                    cache: false
                           }).done(function(data) {
                                if (data.result === true){
                                    alert(data.message);
                               }
                           });
                      });
                  });
            </script>
```

In your views.py:

```
        from django.http import JsonResponse

        def post_form_api(request):
              data = {}
              if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get('form_field1', None) is not None:
                  form_field1 = request.POST.get('form_field1')
                  # save the form data and indicate success
                  data['result'] = True
                  data['message'] = "Form saved successfully"
                  ...
              if request.is_ajax():
                 return JsonResponse(data)
              else:
                 return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Or, if you are using Django forms:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

        def post_form_api(request):
              data = {}
              if request.method == "POST":
                  form = MyDjangoForm(request.POST)
                  # save the form and indicate success or do something else with it
                  data['result'] = True
                  data['message'] = "Form saved successfully"
                  ...
              if request.is_ajax():
                 return JsonResponse(data)
              else:
                 return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

When you are sending data via POST don't forget to pass along your CSRF token as in the example above. This assumes you have a form on the page you can get it from, otherwise you can use something like this to get it:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

If you don't want to deal with the CSRF token, you can mark the view with the `@csrf_exempt` decorator and remove the '`csrfmiddlewaretoken`' data element from the Ajax call in the template, but it may not be ideal or the most secure. An example of that:

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    @csrf_exempt()
    def post_form_api(request):
           ...
```

Now, without knowing more, this is basically just pseudocode (plus I just wrote this off the top of my head so it may have errors). If you post more details I can update my answer, but I think this should get you started.

Comment: late,but: if you don't want to deal with AJAX manually, use HTMX. It's much easier.